# Visual Web Developer Express - Encrypt connection string

Tags: asp.net

I have created a very simple ASP.NET application with a web.config file, which contains a connection string.  The connection string is used to connect to a database and return one value (this works).

I am now trying to encrypt the connection string.  I use the following command (taken from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/Test".
```

The command prompt returns "succeeded", but when I look at the web.config (in the Test folder), nothing has changed.

I have Visual Web Developer Express installed on my development PC.  This is for testing purposes.  Once I am confident with this tool (aspnet_regiis) I will be making a change to a live web app using Visual Studio Professional.

Is there something wrong with the command I am running? Are you not able to encrypt connection strings using Visual Web Developer Express?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `-pe`, I suggest using `-pef` and specifying the path to the directory holding the `web.config` file - this avoid any ambiguity as to what IIS is pointing at.

```
ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "path to directory with web.config"
```

Comment: Thanks.  That has worked.  Could you explain what you mean by: "this avoid any ambiguity ".  Also do you know how to decrypt the web.config?

Comment: @w0051977 - To decrypt you use the `-pdf` flag. My point about "ambiguity" is that when you specify a web application name, you may think IIS is pointing to one directory but it may be pointing to a different one. When specifying a directory, there is no way to be confused about where the file exists.

Comment: Again, thanks that has worked.  Do you know what path will be used if I juat select: test, instead of the full path?

Comment: @w0051977 - No. It will depend on the current working directory.

Comment: @w0051977 - In what environment? If you specify the full path, this is not an issue.